# Separate RoutePrefix attribute on partial Web API v2 controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am following an RPC approach in one of my Web APIs and for that purpose i am gonna use attribute routing in my controllers.

I am splitting my Controllers by making them `partial`:

[Folder structure pic](http://s23.postimg.org/6ffy0nk0r/controllerstructure.jpg)

ALL the partial files under JDE folder must have the same RoutePrefix and actions will make the url unique.

```
namespace Enterprise.Api.Controllers.JDE.Distribution
{
    [RoutePrefix("/api/jde/distribution")]
    public partial class JDEController : ApiController
    {

    }
}
```

I want every partial file to have its own route prefix and every action to have a route.

If i put `RoutePrefix` in more than one file i get an error.

Answer (score 2):

Partial files of a class are still considered as one single class and so you cannot use multiple route prefix attributes...consider creating multiple controller types for your scenario...

Answer (score 1):

So what i did is this:

First i add this ONE time to my partial APi controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/jde")]
public partial class JDEController : ApiController
{
    public JDEController()
    {

    }
}
```

And then i add a Route attribute in my methods to get what i want

```
public partial class JDEController : ApiController
{

    [Route("orders")]
    public IEnumerable<Order> Get(int customerId) { ... }
}
```

Comment: You also only need to inherit ApiController once, so I would suggest having it only in the partial class containing the constructor 'public partial class JDEController : ApiController'

Comment: is there any way so we can use it like this but we inherit APIController in all partial class , in my case i have generic controller that contains some generics methods so i need to use them in every partial class